# window.frames didn't releases the array key after when frame was deleted or renamed in firefox 22, 23

Tags: firefox, frames, firefox-22

Simple thing happens with a Firefox 22 and higher: if you have a frame with a name `"name1"` and you renamed it to `"name2"` then the `"name1"` still will be present in a `window.frames` array but it's value would be `undefined`. The same thing happens if you call `delete window.frames["name1"];`.

The problem is that you couldn't directly place any item into `frames` array with a name `"name1"` in this case. Also you couldn't add the property `name1` into that window object. 
The only way to do this is change the some frame name to `"name1"`. However our current application logic need to access the same frame both by `"name1"` and `"name2"` in the same time.

Here the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/tigeral/2VwFV/2/ .Please compare results in both Firefox 21 and 22.

Does anyone know a workaround how to make follow code working ?

```
window.frames["name1"].name = "name2";
// what I need to do here ?    
window.frames["name1"] = window.frames["name2"];
alert(window.frames["name1"].name);
```

P.s. the similar question was already posted on Stack Overflow, but my case requires a different solution. window.frames["frame_name"] doesn't work in Firefox when frame has been removed and readded

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
If you need to force set the `frames["name1"]` value just once you can use `Object.defineProperty(frames, "name1", {value: frames["name2"]});` sentance. 
But if you also want to unlock the `frames["name1"]` value for the future changes then you'd better use `Object.defineProperty(frames, "name1", {value: frames["name2"], writable: true});`

You can check this solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/2VwFV/3/ or in sample below:

```
window.frames["name1"].name = "name2";
Object.defineProperty(frames, "name1", {writable: true});    
window.frames["name1"] = window.frames["name2"];
alert(window.frames["name1"].name);
```

More info about Object.defineProperty(...) method could be found by follow link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty